# How to get common elements in array using project in pymongo aggregate

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

The following code gets the count of **type** for each user separately.

```
DB.ticket.aggregate([
        {
            '$match': {'project': project_id},
        },
        {
            '$group': { 
                '_id': {
                    'assignee': "$assignee.uid",
                    'type': "$type"
                }, 
                'count': { '$sum': 1} 
            },
            
        },
        {
            "$project": {'assignee': "$_id.assignee", 'type': "$_id.type", 'count': 1, "_id":0}
        }
    ])
```

Following is the output.

```
[
    {
        "assignee": "John",
        "count": 2,
        "type": "Open"
    },
    {
        "assignee": "John",
        "count": 3,
        "type": "Completed"
    },
    {
        "assignee": "Jason",
        "count": 2,
        "type": "In Progress"
    },
    {
        "assignee": "Jason",
        "count": 2,
        "type": "Completed"
    }
]
```

I want the following output, wherein pymongo aggregation project section code tweaks the output to show the ouput listed based on one primary key element which is the **assignee** in this case.

```
“John”: [
        {
            "count": 2,
            "type": "Open"
        },
        {
            "count": 3,
            "type": "Completed"
        }
    ],
“Jason”: [
        {
            "count": 2,
            "type": "In Progress"
        },
        {
            "count": 2,
            "type": "Completed"
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to add 3 more steps:

1. `$group` by the `assignee`
2. `$group` to insert all documents into one document
3. Create an object (dictionary) using `$arrayToObject`

```
  {$group: {
      _id: "$assignee",
      v: {$push: {count: "$count", type: "$type"}}
  }},
  {$group: {
      _id: 0,
      data: {$push: {k: "$_id", v: "$v"}}
    }
  },
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$arrayToObject: "$data"}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lpDZKk9NII3)